# Is it possible to run a selenium webdriver automated test in Azure DevOps for my website that is already deployed elsewhere?

Tags: azure, selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

My website is already deployed and can be accessed by a server I've already provisioned.

I created an automated selenium webdriver test in Visual Studio to test my website. Now I want this to run on a nightly basis automatically, would it be possible to use Azure DevOps for this? I've been checking tutorials on running Automated Tests in Azure DevOps and it always includes deploying the website in Azure DevOps too, which is not applicable for my site.

Comment: Not get your latest information,if the answer is helpful, please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442), just click the option like this . Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently testing this where I'm just running the test.

This is what my Azure pipeline looks like:

[image: Azure Pipeline]

Basically we have a console app running the test (With NUnit) on the server.

We deploy the app that contains all the tests. We have variables for the URL to use in the pipeline with the login user etc that will populate our runsettings file.

[image: Pipeline Variables sample]

We then create a Virtual VS Session then run the .dll containing the selenium tests.

Export the .trx report and mail it out.

Hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want this to run on a nightly basis automatically, would it be
> possible to use Azure DevOps for this? I've been checking tutorials on
> running Automated Tests in Azure DevOps and it always includes
> deploying the website in Azure DevOps too, which is not applicable for
> my site.

Yes, it's possible. If your source code is in Azure Devops repo, you can add [Visual Studio build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) to generate the test assembly. And then use [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) to run the tests.

Or if you've got the test assembly in one path, just specify the `search folder` and `Test files`:

[image]

You don't need deploy-related tasks since your website is deployed. Just make sure your website is running, and then [install self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) in the server you've already provisioned. Run the pipeline with that self-hosted agent from `Default` agent pool, then you can run tests easily for your website.